# jQuery onClick for <li> element not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, selector

Strangely, the following code throws a jQuery.Deferred exception:

```
var miscUls = $("#miscellaneous").find("ul");
miscUls.children('li')[0].onClick(function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
});
```

...and...

```
miscUls.children().first().onClick(....
```

...and

```
miscUls.children('li').eq(0).onClick(....
```

not quite sure *how* to stylize the selector, I'm merely trying to attach an onClick() event handler to the first element in that unordered list. I *have* also tried to assign a unique id to that element, and select it via

```
miscUls.getElementById("newUser").onClick(....
```

to no avail. Any help with this seemingly simple problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery's click event helper is [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) not onClick

```
var miscUls = $("#miscellaneous").find("ul");
miscUls.children('li')[0].click(function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. I'm not familiar with js typing so these small variations in syntax catch me.

Answer (score 1):

try `:first-child` selector on `li` like this

```
$("#miscellaneous ul li:first-child").click(function(){
        // your code
    })
```